# Can I break my BLDC motor by connecting an ESC in the wrong way?

Tags: dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, short-circuit

I've got a brushless DC-motor and an ESC. The ESC has three wires and the motor 8 (of which 5 are for the Hall sensor). The 3 wires of the ESC are not colored or marked, so I just wanted to try some different attachment variations until it works.

If I attach it wrong I would assume it would simply not work. I don't want to run the risk of breaking stuff though. Is it possible that I somehow physically mess up my DC-motor or ESC by attaching it the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't using the Hall sensors, then you can hook up the three drive wires any way without causing damage.  Of the six possible choices, 3 will drive the motor one way for "forward", and the other three the other direction.  The three choices within each direction are then essentially equivalent.

If you are using the Hall sensors, then you do need to hook up the drive lines in a way that matches the Hall inputs.  If you get it wrong, the motor could be driven to a fixed angle and then stop.  The motor will dissipate power as if it were being driven normally but stalled.

At low power, that should cause no damage.  At full power, it could overheat the motor, depending on whether the motor is rated to handle the full stall current indefinitely or not.

Comment: Great, thanks a million! I've already ordered a full fledged BLDC motor driver including a Hall sensor, but before that arrives (which will be another 3 weeks) I want to test it out with an ESC. I'm happy that I'm not running any risks when not attaching the hall sensor. Well, I'm off to work on my project again (a kite flying robot). I wish you a beautiful day!

Comment: Assuming of course the ESC and BDLC are compatible.....